# Display images in auto scrolling horizontalscrolview

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview, autoscroll

I'm using horizontalscrollView to move set of images as a slideshow. I've 5 images in drawable, I'm able to move images from right to left but in some phones it just scrolling to 3rd image and restarting the scroll and in some phones it just stops scrolling till reaching to the end of images in right. Please help !! This is the code I used :

```
 public void getScrollMaxAmount(){
    int actualWidth = (horizontalOuterLayout.getMeasuredWidth()-200);
    scrollMax   = actualWidth;
}

public void startAutoScrolling(){
    if (scrollTimer == null) {
        scrollTimer=new Timer();
        final Runnable Timer_Tick=new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                moveScrollView();
            }
        };

        if(scrollerSchedule != null){
            scrollerSchedule.cancel();
            scrollerSchedule = null;
        }
        scrollerSchedule = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
            }
        };

        scrollTimer.schedule(scrollerSchedule, 50, 50);
    }
}

public void moveScrollView(){
    scrollPos= (int) (hsv2.getScrollX() + 1.0);
    if(scrollPos >= scrollMax){
        scrollPos=0;
    }
    hsv2.scrollTo(scrollPos, 0);
}

public void addImagesToView(){
    for (int i=0;i<imageNameArray.length;i++){
        Log.d("imagname",String.valueOf(imageNameArray.length));
        final ImageView imageButton =   new ImageView(this);
    int imageResourceId      =  getResources().getIdentifier(imageNameArray[i], "drawable",getPackageName());
     Drawable image  =  this.getResources().getDrawable(imageResourceId);

        imageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(image);
        imageButton.setTag(i);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params    =   new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(90,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //params.setMargins(0, 25, 0, 25);
        imageButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        horizontalOuterLayout.addView(imageButton);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
First calculate width of your scrollview like this here linearlayout is layout inside your scrollview 


    linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    LayoutParams layParamsGet = linearLayout.getLayoutParams();
                    width = layParamsGet.width;

                }
            });


Then in timertassk just scroll the scrollview upto end

private void callAsynchronousTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        if (x <= width - KeyConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH) {
                            x = x + 1;
                        } else {

                            x = 0;
                        }

                        mhorizontalscrollView.scrollTo(x, 0);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 5);
}
```

Comment: I tried putting 512 instead but it's still not working.. with 200 it is scrolling upto last image and stopping there ..